# my windows application crashing frequently on startup

Tags: windows, flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an application on windows 10 in Flutter 2.x.x. I am implementing bluetooth functionality with the app. The problem is that application is mostly crashing on startup. It is working only once I tried several times after it crashes.

The error message is just `Lost connection to device.`

Could you help me on it?

Comment: Crashing and stopping with an error message are two different things

Comment: It doesn't have an error message of the app. Lost connection to device is the message from adb.